# 1 sock.execute transaction with 2 data structures

Tags: python, odoo

I have read that it is possible to  record a partner and their addresses, all in a single call to the web service. The examples always call 2 sock.execute

```
partner = {
   'name': 'Fabien Pinckaers',
   'lang': 'fr_FR',
}

partner_id = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.partner', 'create', partner)

address = {
    'partner_id': partner_id,
    'type' : 'default',
    'street': 'Chaussée de Namur 40',
    'zip': '1367',
    'city': 'Grand-Rosière',
    'phone': '+3281813700',
    'fax': '+3281733501',
}

address_id = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.partner.address', 'create', address)
```

But how do i call this as 1 transaction in 1 sock.execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
partner = {

    'name': 'Fabien Pinckaers',
    'lang': 'fr_FR',
    'address': [(0,0,{
        'type': 'default',
        'street': 'Chaussée de Namur 40',
        'zip': '1367',
        'city': 'Grand-Rosière',
        'phone': '+3281813700',
        'fax': '+3281733501',
    })]
}
```

or try like this:

```
  address = {
    'type' : 'default',
    'street': 'Chaussée de Namur 40',
    'zip': '1367',
    'city': 'Grand-Rosière',
    'phone': '+3281813700',
    'fax': '+3281733501',
}

partner = {
   'name': 'Fabien Pinckaers',
   'lang': 'fr_FR',
}

partner.update({'address': [(0,0,address)]})
```

Hope this helpful